# Extracting a factor from a symbolic algebra equation

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

In `Mathematica` if I have a symbolic algebra equation, how can I get the factor which is multiplied by a specific term?

I mean, say, as the result of some calculation I get a symbolic equation `a x^2 + b x + c y`, and say I am interested in whatever is multiplied by `x^2` (i.e. `a` in here). What statement should I write such that if applied to `a x^2 + b x + c y` returns `a`.

(note that in the example there is a `b x` term so I cannot use derivatives to extract the factor)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe what you are asking for is how to extract a coefficient. For polynomial expressions you can use something like this:

```
In[1]:=  Coefficient[(x+y)^3, xy^2]
Out[1]:= 3
```

More generally, if you want to get all the coefficients, you can use `CoefficientList` like so:

```
In[1]:= f = a x^2 + b x + c;
CoefficientList[f, x]

Out[2]= {c, b, a}
```

Comment: I've added an example using `CoefficientList` in case someone was looking to extract all coefficients. Feel free to rollback.

Comment: what I am working with is not a polynomial, yet this works, thanks